# .NET MAUI FlyoutItem load parameter

Tags: maui

I have a Shell application using `FlyoutItem` with multiple `ShellContents` using the same `ContentPage` and `ViewModel`, as the only difference is the loaded content, layout and api calls are the same. That's why I need to pass some parameter to it when loading the Page/ViewModel.

The only ways I can find to do this are:
override `OnNavigated` in the `AppShell` and `OnNavigatedTo` in the `ContentPage` to get the breadcrumb and call the method of my ViewModel passing the parameter to it, isn't there some more elegant way?

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args)
{
    string route = Shell.Current.CurrentItem.CurrentItem.CurrentItem.Route;
    await Vm.SearchQueryAsync(route);

    base.OnNavigatedTo(args);
}
```

In this case, the breadcrumb matches the parameter I want to pass.

Comment: You can refer to the article about the [How to pass parameter to FlyoutItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/934104/how-to-pass-parameter-to-flyoutitem-gtshellcontent.html). This is an effective way to navigate the page.

Comment: This seems to be a workaround until there is a possibility to add parameters:
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3868#issuecomment-1329418781